# PHP SQL Has an issue

Tags: sql

This is my table, I should fetch the `MAX (id)`  of each `status_id.`

```
id      status_id
10          1
11          1
12          2
13          2
14          2
15          4
16          4
```

So, I use this sql query, it works true and fetchs me all max ID.

```
select status_id, max(id) as max FROM `table` 
where status_id in (1,2,3,4) group by status_id
```

This sql command fetchs me 3 MAX id using while.

11, 14, 16....

You see, there is not any suitable id to 3rd `status_id`.  And if there is not any suitable id to 3rd `status_id` just mark it as zero. So I want that sql will bring these results:

11, 14, 0, 16

Comment: I don't see status_id 3 in your table. so dont expect to get 0

Comment: Yes, you dont see. And I want that if there is not status id 3 on my table, sql brings zero

Comment: what about using `IFNULL`...?

Comment: Like this:
The max id of 1st status_id is 11
The max id of 2nd status_id is 14
The max id of 3rd status id is 0
The max id of 4th status_id is 16

Comment: @DipeshParmar, I did not try if null yet. Maybe it will help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a subquery which basically has all the `ID`'s  you need and have a left join against it.

```
SELECT  a.status_ID,
        IFNULL(MAX(b.id), 0) maxVal
FROM    
        (
            SELECT 1 status_ID UNION ALL 
            SELECT 2 UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 UNION ALL
            SELECT 4 
        ) a
        LEFT JOIN `table` b ON a.status_id = b.status_id
GROUP   BY a.status_id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab2a98/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can join with a temporary dummy table containing all ids and a stats_id value of 0:

```
SELECT dummy.status_id, COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) AS max
FROM (
        SELECT 1 status_id
  UNION SELECT 2 status_id
  UNION SELECT 3 status_id
  UNION SELECT 4 status_id
) dummy
LEFT JOIN `table` 
ON dummy.status_id = table.status_id
GROUP BY dummy.status_id
```

But this does not scale and is a maintenance nightmare (you have to change the dummy-select in case a new status_id turns up). If you have a table containing ALL status_ids, replace the dummy-select with that table.